# Oracle Table to XSD

Tags: oracle, xsd

How do I create `XSD` from an Oracle Table? Are there any tools available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way.

You can create POJO from Database in hibernate in java.
Then from java Pojos you can create XSD. using schemagen.

> DB -> POJO -> Schemagen

Comment: if u don't want to go for it go for http://www.altova.com/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=1000000195

Comment: @Shyam I would like to know which way you have selected finally?